# How to compile .m4s segments for vimeo player?

Tags: video, streaming, wget

I'm trying to scrap some videos from a website that requires to login. I tried to use `youtube-dl` with the `--cookies` parameter but it says unsupported URL. I tried to feed it some URLs I got by selecting the player with a web inspector but to no avail. All I got are the XHR requests, it starts with a `json` file that contains all the segments names and then the `m4s` segments are requested when the video advances.

After downloading them with `wget`, I tried to concatenate them into one file and at first I had the audio but the visual was like it was "encrypted". And now when I retry I get `can't find the track`.

Is it possible to find a way to compile those segments into one file if I tell you that's it's a vimeo player ? If not what information would one need to be able to do that ?